# Add model to collection after fetching it

Tags: backbone.js

Im having trouble figuring out how to populate a model's attributes from the server and then add the populated model to a collection and have that collection rendered by a view. Here's the code I have:

```
var movieDetails = new cinephile.Models.MovieDetailsModel({ id: movie.get('id') });
this.collection.add(movieDetails);
```

Inside of the MovieDetailsModel:

```
cinephile.Models.MovieDetailsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    url: function()
    {
        return '/cinephile/api/index.php?action=getMovieDetails&movieId=' + this.id;
    },

    initialize: function()
    {
        this.fetch();
    }
});
```

And `this.collection` is just a collection with the model set to be a `cinephile.Models.MovieDetailsModel`

I am listening for items to be added to the collection and when they are, the following is executed:

```
displayMovie: function(movie)
{
    var view = new cinephile.Views.MovieView({
        model: movie,
        className: 'movie clearfix',
        template: JST['app/scripts/templates/MovieView.ejs'],
    });

    this.$("#my-movies").append(view.el);
},
```

MovieView looks like this:

```
cinephile.Views.MovieView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(options)
    {
        this.template = options.template;
        this.render();
    },

    render : function()
    {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;    
    },
});
```

The problem I have is that the template I'm using is trying to access an attribute of the model that is undefined. Im pretty sure it's undefined because the MoveDetailsModel hasn't finished fetching before the model is added to the collection and subsequently rendered to the view.

How can I solve this issue? I'd like to be able to create a MovieDetailsModel that takes in an id, use that id to get the movie details from the server and then add the populated model to a collection and then render that collection to the screen.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you pass a callback to your [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Backbone fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) returns a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object, which is a Deferred objects Promise.
When fetch is called, the attributes are not populated yet. Promise objects have a don
ejqXHR function, where a callback can be passed to be executed once the request is done.

I would recommend moving the fetch into another method not the constructor, because there You can return the jqXHR object and access its done function.
Here is an example:

```
var movieDetails = new cinephile.Models.MovieDetailsModel({ id: movie.get('id') });
var promise = movieDetails.fetch();
promise.done(function() {
    var view = new cinephile.Views.MovieView({model: movieDetails});
    view.render();
});
```